# Where is the tensor product of two unit vectors projection onto?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I know that $\bar{e} \otimes \bar{e}$ is a projection onto $\bar{e}$.

Then, I start to think where is then $\bar{e}_{i} \otimes  \bar{e}_{j}$ projection onto.

**Where is the expression $\bar{e}_{i} \otimes  \bar{e}_{j}$ projection onto?**

It is likely a third vector like $\bar{e}_{k}$ that is orthogonal to the two unit vectors, like in vector calculus for cross-product.
But then again, this is not possible if $\bar{e}$ is in line with the vectors in $\bar{e} \otimes \bar{e}$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to line up with the standard definition of tensor product. Perhaps you could explain what you mean by tensor products in this context and how you are relating them to projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean by "tensor product" is the outer product (i.e., for vectors $a$ and $b$, the product $a\otimes b$ is the matrix $ab^{T}$, with elements $a_i b_j$), then you can write the following in general:
$$
(a\otimes b)\cdot c = \sum_{i, j}\left(a_ib_jc_j\right)e_i.
$$
If $a$ and $b$ are unit vectors, then you have
$$
(e_a\otimes e_b)\cdot c = \sum_{i, j}\left((e_a)_i (e_b)_jc_j\right)e_i=\sum_{i,j}\delta_{ai}\delta_{bj}c_je_i=(c \cdot e_b)e_a.
$$
That is, the product projects $c$ onto the $b$-axis, then rotates the result onto the $a$-axis.  In general, $\left(a\otimes b\right)$ isn't a projection, but a projection followed by a rotation and dilation.

Comment: I think $(\textbf{a} \bigotimes \textbf{b})$ is still a projection tensor if projection is defined as the transformation of points and lines in one plane onto another plane by connecting corresponding points on the two planes with parallel lines. Then, I would say that the projectin is onto the plane formed after a rotation and dilation made by **b** and **a**, respectively.

Comment: I am thinking your statement here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557354/show-that-the-tensor-product-is-followed-by-a-rotation-and-a-dilation